# Форма учёта времени

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Необходимо создать форму учёта рабочего времени для 10-15 человек. Так, чтобы каждый работник мог бы, зайдя в свою учётную запись, зарегистрировать свои отработанные часы. А начальник, в свою очередь, имел бы возможность в конце месяца видеть общее количество часов по каждому работнику. На эту тему имеется множество различных решений онлайн, в виде мобильных приложений и.т.п. Вопрос: Возможно ли реализовать эту идею средствами WordPress и Gravity Forms, например?

Comment: Практика показывает, что средствами WP можно реализовать множество идей, включая эту. Вопрос только в том, зачем это вам, если есть более подходящие для этого инструменты и решения

Comment: Коллектив уже давно использует определённую систему учёта рабочего времени, к которой все привыкли. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы перенести эту систему, не меняя её внутренней логики, с бумажной версии в цифровую. Существующие решения имеют либо иной подход, либо обладают излишней функциональностью

Comment: Тогда ответ на ваш вопрос - да, такую систему на WP реализовать можно.